# If a function is equal to an integrable function almost everywhere, is it integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesuge-integrable function, and $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ a function such that $f=g$ almost everywhere.
I can prove that if $g$ is Lebesgue-measurable, then $g$ is Lebesgue-integrable. But is the condition that $g$ is Lebesgue-measurable necessary?

Comment: $f$ Lebesgue measurable, $f=g$ a.e. implies $g$ Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Curiously, the book I'm reading does not mention that fact. Can you give me a hint how to prove it?

Comment: Completeness of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It follows from the fact that $g=f+(g-f)$ and the fact that both $f$ and $g-f$ are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar yet with measure theory; why is $g-f$ Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kavi Rama Murthy and @José Carlos Santos's hints, I looked up the book I was reading (Berberian's *Fundamentals of Real Analysis*) and found a proof (really an exercise problem with a hint) that in a complete measure space $X$, if $f=g$ a.e. and $f$ is measurable, then $g$ is measurable:

Let $N\subset X$ be a null set outside of which $f=g$. Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and
$$A=\{x\in X\mid f(x)>c\}\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad B=\{x\in X\mid g(x)>c\}.$$
Since $f$ is measurable, $A$ is measurable.
We will show that $B$ is measurable.
Clearly $A-B\subset N$ and $B-A\subset N$.
Since $X$ is complete, $A-B$ and $B-A$ are measurable. Then
$$B=(A-(A-B))\cup(B-A)$$
is measurable.

Thanks guys! (I have to say that the proof is not at all trivial.)

Comment: Also, note that the above property is essentially equivalent to the measure space being complete. More precisely: If $(X, \cal{M}, \mu)$ is not complete, then one can find $f, g : X \to \Bbb R$ such that $f = g$ a.e., $f$ is measurable, but $g$ is not.

Comment: Thanks! It was a genuine typo. (Of course I didn't mean metric space.) I corrected it. Thanks again!